# Table showed different in IE from Opera

Tags: html, internet-explorer, html-table, opera

I have a table with a code like this:

```
<table cellpadding="6" rules="groups"  frame="no">
<thead>
<tr><th>Date</th><th>Length</th><th>Time</th></tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
<tr><td>31. January1</td><td>28 km</td><td>3 hours</tr> 
</tbody></table>
```

The problem is that in IE the table has frame and a tableborder = 1.
What to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Example:Table with Header Underline Border</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        table.groups
        {
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }

        table.groups thead th
        {
            border-bottom: solid 1px black;
        }

        table.groups th,
        table.groups td
        {
            padding: 6px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table class="groups">
        <thead>
            <tr><th>Date</th><th>Length</th><th>Time</th></tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr><td>31. January1</td><td>28 km</td><td>3 hours</td></tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

A couple of specific things to note:

- Using a DOCTYPE to prevent quirks mode.
  (this is the HTML5 DOCTYPE - some people prefer the more wordy XHTML or HTML4 Strict ones - those also work)
- No unnecessary attributes on the tags - all controlled by tag names and classes.

Answer (score 1):

I want it to look like this:

[image]

When I use `border="0"` IE don't display the black line. If I write `<th style="1p solid black>Text</th>` I get a black box around the table heads.

Answer (score 0):

```
border="0"
```

However, you should use stylesheets instead for things like this....

Answer (score 0):

use

style="border:1px solid black"

in the table-tag, then.

oh, and there's a closing  missing for the last cell.